# Visualizing/explaining multilevel model (dichotomous IV)

Tags: data-visualization, stata, multilevel-analysis

I am using multilevel modeling (xtmixed in Stata) to predict a quasi-continuous level-3 DV using a dichotomous IV (sex). My results are markedly different from what the basic difference between men and women would suggest. No problem there - this is why I'm using MLM and not OLS regression or a t-test.

However, I'm having trouble describing the results. In particular, one of my graphs shows the difference in means, and it's more than a little confusing when you compare that to the formal test results. Does anyone know of a way to graphically present this kind of information in an intuitive way, or explain the apparent disparity of results without getting too technical?